# How do I import sounds into my KIVY library on pydroid

Tags: python, audio, error-handling, kivy, libraries

How do I play sounds on Kivy with pydroid?

My code:

```py
from android import activity
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader

sound = SoundLoader.load("intro.wav")
```

But I get:

> [INFO   ] [Audio       ] Providers: audio_sdl2 (audio_android, audio_ffpyplayer ignored)
> [WARNING] [AudioSDL2   ] Unable to load beep-08b.wav: b'Mix_LoadWAV_RW with NULL src'